# Meta sites should count question scores toward tag scores

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta

Questions don't count towards a user's badge score. This might make sense on the main sites, which thrive primarily through *answers* contributed by regular users.

But those same regular users post relevant *questions* (as well as answers) on the meta sites, contributing **bug reports, feature requests, and initiating important discussions** about e.g. policy, thereby *advancing the entire community and providing valuable input for the continued improvement of the SE software*.

For [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), the opening post (question) is ***at least*** as important a contribution to the site as any answer. Most of the top-rated [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions are also important contributions and discuss e.g. moderation policy. Simpler, less relevant support questions don't get a lot of upvotes anyway.

That contributing questions on meta is an important metric for overall meta/community contribution is shown by their inclusion e.g. in moderator election pages.

> [image]

Question also count towards a user's meta site [activity](https://meta.superuser.com/users?tab=activity), therefore making the treatment of question scores inconsistent.

---

**Questions scores on meta sites**, at least the child metas, should therefore **count towards the tag scores**, equal to answers.